# Vaadin Widgetset.gwt.xml inherits-tag automatically removed on compile

Tags: maven, vaadin, maven-plugin, vaadin7, vaadin8

Recently we updated Vaadin 7 to Vaadin 8. One of our components wasn't working, and when analyzing the problem today I found it was due to still being Vaadin 7, and having mismatches. So I updated the component to Vaadin 8 (although still using all the `.v7` libraries for now, and added the `@Widgetset("com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet")` on the UI class, as well as added the `vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled` maven dependency.
Our test-WAR of this component was working as it should again, and I deployed this new version to our Nexus (with a TODO to actually update all the Vaadin 7 and Viritin components to Vaadin 8).

Now in our main project (where we use this component) I've updated it's version in the `pom.xml`, but when running it gave the same error as before I added the `@Widgetset` to the component's UI-class. Our main project already has an `@Widgetset` with a custom Widgetset of ours. I figured I'd just add the `com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet` as `<inherits>` to this `Widgetset.gwt.xml` file of our main project, but when I do and save, some Maven plugin autmatically resets it to what it was.

This is what our `Widgetset.gwt.xml` currently looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
        "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />

    <stylesheet src="resetbuttonfortextfield/styles.css" />
</module>
```

And when I try to add these two lines:

```
<!-- TODO: Remove following inherit after Templates Component has been migrated to Vaadin 8 -->
<inherits name="com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet" />
```

Only the TODO-comment remains after saving. Since my co-workers for this project all live on the other side of the world where it's currently evening, I can't really contact them for help, so I resort to StackOverflow instead.

Here is our `pom.xml` as reference, and I think something here causes the `Widgetset.gwt.xml` to reset after I save it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
      <groupId>our.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>web-parent</artifactId>
      <version>develop-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>web2-widgetset</artifactId>
  <name>web2-widgetset</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Versions for these are configured in the parent POM -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
      <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024M -Xss2048k</extraJvmArgs>
          <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
          <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
          <compileReport>false</compileReport>
          <!-- Change to PRETTY (or possibly DETAILED) to get unobfuscated client side stack traces. A better approach for debugging is to use Super Dev  Mode -->
          <style>OBF</style>
          <strict>true</strict>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Vaadin-Package-Version>1</Vaadin-Package-Version>
              <Vaadin-Widgetsets>our.project.Widgetset</Vaadin-Widgetsets>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
          <!-- Exclude some unnecessary files generated by the GWT compiler. -->
          <excludes>
            <exclude>VAADIN/gwt-unitCache/**</exclude>
            <exclude>VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

I'm assuming the `vaadin-maven-plugin` with `<goal>update-widgetset</goal>` is responsible for removing my `<inherits>`-tag in the `Widgetset.gwt.xml`, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm still relatively new to Maven in general.
But if I'm right, how do I modify the `pom.xml` so it will also add this `<inherits>`-tag I need?

**TL;DR:** How to permanently add an additional `<inherits>`-tag in my `Widgetset.gwt.xml` (without having some plugin in our Maven `pom.xml` overwrite these manual changes)?

---

EDIT: If I comment out `<goal>update-widgetset</goal>` the `Widgetset.gwt.xml` isn't updated anymore, but it is giving an error in the `pom.xml`:

```
GWT Module com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet not found in project sources or resources. (com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:8.0.6:compile:default:process-classes)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GWT Module com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet not found in project sources or resources.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:701)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:435)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at com.vaadin.integration.eclipse.maven.VaadinMojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(VaadinMojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.utils.GwtModuleReaderException: GWT Module com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet not found in project sources or resources.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtModuleMojo.readModule(AbstractGwtModuleMojo.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getLocalInherits(GwtModule.java:189)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getInherits(GwtModule.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.GwtModule.getEntryPoints(GwtModule.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compilationRequired(CompileMojo.java:615)
    ... 36 more
```

Which is already a great step in the right direction of what caused the `<inherits>` to be removed automatically. Seems like I need to figure out the relevant dependency and add it to the `pom.xml` if I understand correctly.

Comment: did you try, https://github.com/vaadin/framework8-migration-tool  (just wondering)

Comment: @petey Ah, no. Not for this Component. I think my coworker has used it when we migrated our main project to Vaadin 8 now that I see it, though.. At the readme of that git you've linked it does state at "_The tool does not, and you need to_" I should manually change `vaadin-client` and `vaadin-client-compiled` to their `compatibility` version, though. When I have some time I might go back to an old git tag and try it for the component, see what's different with my manual changes.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, fixed. I came across this post of someone else migrating Vaadin 7 to 8 and having some issues with the Widgetset: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/15031831/15036434

And the first reply (which I quote here) solved my problem:

> Hi, good to know that you are enjoying the new version :) Check the following:
>
> - You have to **replace** the `vaadin-server` dependency with `vaadin-compatibility-server`.
> - If you are using the default widgetset (you are not compiling it by yourself):
>
>   - **Replace** the `vaadin-client-compiled` dependency with `vaadin-compatibility-client-compiled`.
>   - Add `@Widgetset("com.vaadin.v7.Vaadin7WidgetSet")` to your UI implementations.
> - If you are using a custom widgetset:
>
>   - **Replace** the `vaadin-client` dependency with `vaadin-compatibility-client`.
>   - Recompile it.

So I changed `vaadin-client` with `vaadin-compatibility-client` in our Widgetset's  `pom.xml` and now the `<inherits>`-tag remains.